# Taking values from dialog box

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am making a GUI for a download manager.
When the OK button is clicked, I would like the command `execute` to be launched. I would like it to take the values from my `dl_dialog` function i.e. `url`, `path`, `md5url` and feed them to my downloader module.

The issue is the values of `url`, `path` and `md5url` do not update to the ones I have typed into the entry field. How can I fix this?

```
default_storage_path= "C:\sdmdownloads"
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Download", command=self.dl_dialog)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.path = default_storage_path
        self.url = ""
        self.md5url = ""
        self.filename = ""

    def dl_dialog(self):
        self.dialog = Pmw.Dialog(root,
            buttons = ('OK', 'Apply', 'Cancel', 'Help'),
            defaultbutton = 'OK',
            title = 'My dialog',
            command = self.execute)

        lbl1 = Tkinter.Label(self.dialog.interior(),text="URL")
        lbl1.pack(side="left")

        url = Tkinter.Entry(self.dialog.interior())
        url.pack(side="left")
        self.url = url

        lbl2 = Tkinter.Label(self.dialog.interior(),text="Path")
        lbl2.pack(side="left")

        path = Tkinter.Entry(self.dialog.interior())
        path.pack(side="left")
        path.insert(0,default_storage_path)
        self.path = path

        lbl3 = Tkinter.Label(self.dialog.interior(),text="MD5 URL")
        lbl3.pack(side="left")

        md5url = Tkinter.Entry(self.dialog.interior())
        md5url.pack()
        self.md5url = md5url

    def execute(self):
        #if result not in ('Apply', 'Help'):
        #    self.dialog.deactivate(result)

        if result == "OK":
            print "OK"
            path =self.path
            url = self.url
            md5url = self.md5url


            d = Downloader(path,url,md5url)
            thread.start_new_thread(d.checkhttplink, ())
            thread.start_new_thread(d.checkifexists, ())
        elif result == "Apply":
            print "Apply"
        elif result == "Cancel":
            print "Cancel"
        else:
            print"Help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed...Sorry forgot to use my StringVar()

Comment: Glad that you have this working for you, however, your answer does not really indicate how you fixed your issue.  Can you post your complete, working solution as part of your answer?